# Swift : how to blurry a cell on tap in tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, addsubview

I have a tableView that displays photos.
I just want to add a subView in order to make a blur effect on  the top of the cell.
My problem is that when i add the subView using didSelectRowAtIndex Method, my subView (my blur) is added to the reused cells...

Here is what i did :

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell:WallTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as WallTableViewCell



    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = cell.imagePosted.bounds


    cell.imagePosted.insertSubview(blurEffectView, atIndex: indexPath.row)


}
```

Is there a way to add the blur effect using a tap recognizer, so when i tap the blur is added and when i tap a second time the blur is removed ? And how to add the blur only on the cell who was tapped ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is the wrong method to call here.

You want to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, which is a method on the table view that returns the cell actually being displayed by the table view.  What you're using, `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, provides a "fresh" cell from the re-use queue.

Also, you almost certainly don't want to add/remove subviews in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Instead, you should probably add the blur subviews as part of your original cell design, set them to `hidden=true`, and then enable them by setting `hidden=false`.

Comment: thanks for this but how to detect the cell to blurry with a tap gesture recognizer inside cellForRowAtIndexPath ? Il i add a target with let tap : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
            cell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            tap.addTarget(self, action: "blurry")
How can i get the indexpath ?